# Draw d3-axis with react, without direct D3 DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, d3.js

Im making a data visualization using d3 and react. Im trying to use react to render and d3 just for make calculations.

To draw X-Axis I have a `<g>` with a reference and to render the X-axis I just use:

```
const drawAxis = (graphData: graphData[], refXAxis: any, refYAxis: any, xScale: ScaleD3, yScale: ScaleD3): void => {
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    let a = d3.select(refXAxis).call(xAxis);
    d3.select(refYAxis).call(yAxis); // so, this line manipulates DOM, I want to do *this* with react.
};
```

Is it possible to make this in `react` way?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use d3 only for computations, as you said, so use d3 only to create ticks.

You have `xScale` and `yScale` so you have the ranges.
You can create a simple horizontal `line` with `x1 = xScale.range()[0]` and `x2 = xScale.range()[1]`. And similar for the vertical axis, using the `yScale.range()` values.

Then you can get all the ticks values simply doing `const ticks = xScale.ticks()` and so on.

Doing in this way you have some advantages:

- you don't need references that are not so good in React
- you can control the DOM creation as you want

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-axis-gnih7) an example